# Javascript How to migrate promise.spread syntax to async/await with destructuring

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await, spread-syntax

I'm cleaning up some `sequelize` code and the `findOrCreate` function returns a promise that requires spreading to get the actual result object.

I'd like to rewrite my code to use `await` instead and, given ES6 supports array destructuring I'd have thought that instead of

```
User.findOrCreate({ where: { mcId }, defaults }).spread((user, created) => {
  // do stuff
})
```

I'd just be able to do

```
const [user, created] = await User.findOrCreate({ where: { mcId }, defaults })
```

but alas that's not the case.

I get the error `(intermediate value) is not iterable`

Is there any special trick to doing this or is what I am trying to do just not possible?

Comment: [Note that .spread() implicitly does .all() but the ES6 destructuring syntax doesn't](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/spread.html) - so, perhaps `const [user, created] = await User.findOrCreate({ where: { mcId }, defaults }).all();`

Comment: weirdly if I do that I get this error `SequelizeDatabaseError: relation "Users" does not exist` — but with the old `spread` notation I get no such error.

Comment: Unless you use a pre 2014 version of sequelize the `findOrCreate` should return an array and assuming it returns a promise then the spread should just work. What is result in: `findOrCreate(...).then(result=>console.log(result))`

Comment: I ended up just not using `findOrCreate`. Will come back to this later if I get time.

Answer (score 7):

I'm using Sequelize v4.37.10 and this worked for me -

```
 const [address, created] = await models.Address.findOrCreate({ where: { pid: 123}, defaults});
```